# Logic symbols in a math paper? Is this correct?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, article-writing, publishing

I am writing a mathematics paper with the intent to publish it in a peer-review journal. I have written something along the lines of

Theorem 2.

(1) something

(2) something else.

(end of Theorem 2).

Then later in the paper, I write (my attempt)

$$f(x)  \hspace{0.2cm}\begin{array}{ll}
         >0 & \mbox{always $\iff$ Thm. 2 (1) $\land$ (2)};\\
        <0 & \mbox{if Thm. 2 $\neg$(1) $\lor$ $\neg$(2)}.\end{array} $$
What I am trying to say is this (I do not have enough room and am looking for something more concise):

$$f(x)  \hspace{0.2cm}\begin{array}{ll}
         >0 & \mbox{for all x if and only if both Theorem 2. (1) and Theorem 2. (2) are true };\\
        <0 & \mbox{if either Theorem 2. (1) or Theorem 2. (2) is not true}.\end{array} $$

Was my attempt correct? acceptable for a peer-review journal?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly then you can drop the second statement because of the if and only if in the first statement, as long as you also mention that $f(x)\ne 0$.

Comment: Is there some sort of page or word limit? I can parse the more densely symbolic one fine, but it's much more annoying to read than the one written in normal english.

Comment: Your "later in that paper" is in the middle of the proof of Theorem2, I suppose?

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  Is the implication that (should at least one of the two theorems be false) $f(x)<0$ for all $x$?   Something else?  I think you left off a quantifier.

Comment: Keep in mind:  the point of good mathematics writing is to be clear and precise.  Efficiency matters, but it is hardly the main goal.  If adding a few words clarifies your meaning, do it.

Comment: If it's a theorem then it's true.  So you can just write $f(x) > 0$.  I don't see why you would look at the consequence of a theorem being false - that's a contradiction and it would imply any statement. The only reason I can see would be a proof by contradiction, but it seems that it's already proven since you're asking about something later in the paper.

Answer (score 6):

I think your notation is too cryptic. It's not clear whether the word "always" in the first line applies to the preceding inequality (namely, $f(x) > 0$) or to the following logical symbol (namely, the $\iff$ symbol). In the second line, it's not clear whether you're saying that $f(x) < 0$ for some $x$ or for all $x$. It's also hard for me to imagine what Theorem 2 could possibly look like in order to make "$\mbox{Thm. 2 (1) $\land$ (2)}$" meaningful.

And besides that, this notation just isn't standard or well-known. You shouldn't use non-standard notation without a good reason, and you should *never* use non-standard notation without explaining exactly what it means.

Math is hard to understand even when it's well-written. Don't make the problem even worse by using unclear notation.

Just use prose instead:

> If preconditions (1) and (2) of Theorem 2 both hold, then for all $x$, $f(x) > 0$. On the other hand, if either precondition (1) or precondition (2) fails to hold, then there exists some $x$ such that $f(x) < 0$.